# column made of other columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hello people I'm trying to make a massive change in folder and subfolder names a directory...so what I did was creating a dataframe that contains the folder path, the folder name, the new name, I was able to create this, but what I want to achieve is create a new column that should replace the old name with the new name in the folder path...so then I can use the os.rename() to rename the folders...

what I did was:

```
for i in range(len(fold_name_pd)):
fold_name_pd.loc[i]['new_path'] = fold_name_pd.loc[i]['original_path'].replace(fold_name_pd.loc[i]['old_folder_name'],fold_name_pd.loc[i]['new_folder_name'])
```

but nothing happened, the thing is, if I try this without the for loop(for a single row) it works, so I don't know what is happening there

Comment: You didn't indent the `for loop`.

Comment: I didn't in my question, but I was aware about the indentation, thank https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64033518/column-made-of-other-columns-in-a-dataframe/64033706#comment113232545_64033518you

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
fold_name_pd["new_path"] = [row["original_path"].replace(row["old_folder"], row["new_folder"])
                              for idx, row in fold_name_pd.iterrows()]
```

Here, the rows are being iterated over and the *old_folder* string is replaced by the *new_folder* string in the *original_path*

The problem in your code was that you try to define new column at each iteration, which is not how to access and create a new column of a pandas DataFrame.